# How can I get a indicator for dropbox in Debian xfce?

Tags: debian, dropbox, xfce

I am using Debian Wheezy with xfce 4.10. I installed dropbox but I couldn't find dropbox indicator. Anybody tell me how can I find the dropbox indicator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/453148/after-upgrading-to-14-04-my-dropbox-notifier-is-missing

To fix this Dropbox error in Ubuntu / Linux Mint / Debian, open a terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dropbox/.dropbox-dist
dropbox start -i
```

It worked perfectly for me!